# Unable to set 'valid' property of Formgroup for reactive form in Angular Unit testing

Tags: angular

I am using reactive form. This property: `getattributeForm: FormGroup;`
is set invalid. So I am not able to cover all testcase.

```
if (!this.getattributeForm.valid) {return}
```

This is always true. Can we make it true, so that I can cover other scenario? `this.getattributeForm.valid` to be set true in angular unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

the valid property of the Angular object FormGroup is inherited from the AbstractControl which has an API here https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl  You will find that the valid is a Read-Only field, so you really can't set it manually.

What you can do is one of the following:

1) use setValue() to set the value of the form to a value that is valid, so that then the valid property will be true.

2) use clearValidators() to remove all validators, which means your FormGroup will always be valid.

With either option, you will have to also call updateValueAndValidity() afterwards to force the form to reevaluate the valid property.

Hope this helps, and if there is something I am missing, please comment and I will do my best to help.

Comment: I used clearValidators() ,but still the form is getting invaild . I set vaue to all controls . Not sure why it is not working.

Comment: after calling clearVaidators() you must also call updateValueAndValidity() so that it reevaluates the valid property.  I'll add this to my answer as well.